# How to freeze the clock for a specific task?

Tags: linux, freeze, clock

For example,

```
# clock-pause
# touch a
# touch b
# convert -draw `date` text_draw.gif
# clock-resume
```

Or, simply

```
# freeze-exec sh -c 'touch a; touch b; convert -draw `date` text_draw.gif'
```

The expected result is the timestamps of `a` and `b`, and the text drawn to the image, are exactly the same.

Is it possible?

Comment: What is it that you're really trying to do? You can use `touch` after the fact to change the dates of an existing file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, it might be possible to write a shared library that overrides `time()`, `gettimeofday()`, and `clock_gettime()` to use static values, and add the library to `$LD_PRELOAD`, which would fool many programs.

Update: Someone implemented this as **`datefudge`** .

Comment: I'll play around the environ `LD_PRELOAD`, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Since I had to implement @grawity's solution, I think it could be nice to share it here:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stddef.h>

/* Frozen time (usual time_t, from UNIX epoch) */
const time_t fixedTime=652789800;

/* Deprecated, thus it seems not to be present in sys/types.h */
struct timezone
{
   int tz_minuteswest;     /* minutes west of Greenwich */
   int tz_dsttime;         /* type of DST correction */
};

/* Typedef for the function ptr to the original gettimeofday */
typedef int (*gettimeofday_t)(struct timeval *tv, struct timezone *tz);

/* original gettimeofday */
gettimeofday_t gettimeofday_orig = NULL;

time_t time(time_t * t)
{
    if(t!=NULL)
        *t=fixedTime;
    return fixedTime;
}

int gettimeofday(struct timeval *tv, struct timezone *tz)
{
    if(tz!=NULL)
    {
        /* forward requests about tz to the original gettimeofday */
        if(gettimeofday_orig==NULL)
        {
            gettimeofday_orig=(gettimeofday_t) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "gettimeofday");
            if(gettimeofday_orig==NULL)
                return -1;
        }
        int ret=gettimeofday_orig(NULL, tz);
        if(!ret)
            return ret;
    }
    if(tv!=NULL)
    {
        tv->tv_sec=fixedTime;
        tv->tv_usec=0;
    }
    return 0;
}

int clock_gettime(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *tp)
{
    (void)clk_id;
    if(tp!=NULL)
    {
        tp->tv_sec=fixedTime;
        tp->tv_nsec=0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
matteo@teoxubuntu:~/cpp/detourtest$ gcc -O3 -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -shared timedetour.c -o libtimedetour.so
matteo@teoxubuntu:~/cpp/detourtest$ LD_PRELOAD=/home/matteo/cpp/detourtest/libtimedetour.so date
sab  8 set 1990, 12.30.00, CEST
```

Answer (score 2):

You *cannot* stop the system clock. However, you can do this:

```
now=$(date +%s.%N)
# $now now contains a Unix timestamp at nanosecond precision
touch -d @$now a b c
convert -draw "$(date -d @$now)" text_draw.gif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do **`touch a b`**. You can also do **`touch a; touch --reference=a b`**.

Comment: Thanks. The task may involves other things then create files, I've changed the example to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a project called [faketime](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime) that does this for you. It uses the LD_PRELOAD and it uses absolute/relative times.

```
libfaketime intercepts various system calls which programs use to
retrieve the current date and time. It can then report faked dates and times
(as specified by you, the user) to these programs. This means you can modify
the system time a program sees without having to change the time system-wide.

libfaketime allows you to specify both absolute dates (e.g., 01/01/2004) and
relative dates (e.g., 10 days ago).
```

This answer is for future references as you already have a working solution.